# How can a URL be linked to a text in a YouTube comment?

Tags: youtube

I know that links can be posted in comments made below YouTube videos, but some addresses are very long and look quite ugly. I may use a URL shortening service to shorten the link, but this is a complication.

Is it possible to hide a link behind a visible clickable text?

Answer (score 9):

To make moderation easier, it is not possible to link a custom text to a URL in Youtube comments. Only plain links are clickable, such as:

- `https://www.example.com/xxxxxxx`
- `http://www.example.com/xxxxx/yyyyy`
- `www.example.com/`
- `example.com`